# position of UILabel to make compatible for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-5, iphone-4

The simple code for making an UILabel for my App is

```
UILabel *todaysGame = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 250)];
todaysGame.text = @"Today's Game";
todaysGame.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:todaysGame];
```

This is perfect for my iPhone 5 screen height but got messed up in iPhone 4 screen. I tried to read the iOS 6's auto layout feature but really did not understand how to do it. I do not want to use Storyboard or NIBs, I want to do that programmatically. How to position the UI elements that are both compatible with iPhone 4 and 5's screen heights.

I also tried to see if this helps instead of using numbers

```
screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
screenSize = screenBound.size;
screenWidth = screenSize.width;
screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

and used "screenHeight" variable into the CGRectMake() method.

I am using Xcode 4.6 and iPhone 5 (iOS 6.1.3) and iPhone 4 for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set frame programmatically in `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of your `UIViewController` or set up `autoresizingMask` property of view.

Set up frame:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568) {
        self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100); // for iPhone 5
    } else {
        self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);
    }
}
```

Or set up `autoresizingMask` in `- (void)viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGFloat height = self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.2 // 20% of parent view
    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height);
    self.label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```

Comment: wow, awesome, worked for me. That's quite simple, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is your desired effect?  Same height, variable height, top margin, etc?

Do you want the label to always be that size? If so, you can turn off the auto resize

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

If you want the label to be the same height as your view...

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

Comment: It's important to note that `NSLayoutConstraint` is only available since iOS 6